# Swapping characters in Strings Python

Tags: python-3.8

I have been trying to make something like an encoder:

here is my idea

```
dict = {
    1: "!",
    2: "@"
}

in = 21 # Input number in

out = ?

print(out) # Returns "@!"
```

Is there any way I could perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is exactly the `translate` function of str:

```
x="12"
y="!@"
in=12
txt=str(in)
mapping = txt.maketrans(x, y)
out=txt.translate(mapping)
```

You can check the complete reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_translate.asp).